# how to upload video file through wysiwyg editor in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, wysiwyg

My home page needs to be a promotional video to be embedded. I thought to create a static block which will contain the video file and I just add that block to the content by updating the layout in admin side.
 But the problem is that I cann't upload a video file through **wysiwyg** editor. Sometime it says "Disallowed Type" . Sometimes it simply don't do anything while uploading file.
 Kindly help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow a new file extension like this in your config.xml:

```
<adminhtml>
    <cms>
        <browser>
            <extensions>
                <allowed>
                    <mp4>1</mp4>
                </allowed>
            </extensions>
        </browser>
    </cms>
</adminhtml>
```

Change or add the Extension in the "allow" node. Make sure, that your Server is configured to Upload bigger files

Comment: Can you please add full file description . ?

Answer (score -2):

goto youtube.com open which video you want then bottom of video three option is there. so you click Embed after that it will show  like this

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dUgra62yOBw?list=PLDxywfIfVjJrva58P_oXhG8zUQAAsOayp" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Then use this in your static block or cms page

Comment: I have already done that and it works fine. But I want to upload from backend admin section, i.e. I want to create a CMS  static block containing a video. I am having problem uploading video through wysiwyg editor.

Comment: You want to upload video through backend right

Comment: Yes. From backend using wysiwyg editor.